# How to force a figure to appear before glossary

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I'm building a glossary to explain technical jargon in a diagram. The diagram should be on the first page of the document and the glossary on following page(s). I'm using the `glossaries` package for this currently. However, the diagram floats to the page after the glossary at the moment. So far I tried using the `H` option of the `float` package and relocating the `printglossaries` statement to no effect. I haven't used the `glossaries` package before and am not dead set on sticking with it, just a choice for looks and convenience.

Here's a MWE of my issue. I'm using Overleaf with XeLateX for a specific font if that matters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{
    name=ipsum,
    description={dolor sit amet}
}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, keepaspectratio=true]{diagram.pdf}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\maketitle
\printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue by adding the necessary missing macros and packages. But if you don't use `\caption` why do you use `figure` at all?

Comment: @campa I corrected my MWE. I'm using sidewaysfigure to insert a full-page pdf image of the diagram.

Comment: OK, but the question in my comment remains: you don't seem to be using a `\caption` so why using a `sidewaysfigure` at all?

Comment: Because I only have rudimentary knowledge of Latex and inserting an image has always coincided with using the figure environment I reckon. I replaced the `sidewaysfigure` environment with `center` and added the parameter `angle=90` to `includegraphics`. Now it works as intended.

Comment: Have you tried to add `\clearpage` before `\printglossary`?

Comment: The _only_ purpose of `figure` (or `sidewaysfigure` is to specify that the figure may be moved. Just use `\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{diagram.pdf}}` to include a rotated image that will not move(or equivalently angle key)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I want to prevent a figure to be plotted beyond a certain part of the document, I use `\FloatBarrier` from the [placeins](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins?lang=en) package.

In your case, I would insert the float barrier just after the diagram, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\usepackage{placeins}

\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{
    name=ipsum,
    description={dolor sit amet}
}

\glsaddall
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, keepaspectratio=true]{diagram.pdf}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\FloatBarrier

\maketitle
\printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```